# UKVI ECO made a mistake on my visa decision

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, nigerian-citizens

The UKVI ECO made a mistake while converting my salary to GBP and ended up using the wrong conversion to judge my visa application and I was denied base on that error caused by the ECO who handled my visa. Please, how do I resolve this as I was not given an option of appeal or administrative review?

[image]

The conversion of 24,000,000.00 NGN per year base on £1=479.063 is £50,097.78 but ECO erroneously omitted 7 as quoted it £5,009.78 then he went ahead to use the mistake to calculate monthly income and gave the quote as 200,000 NGN (£417.481) instead of 2,000,000.00 (£4,174.81) per month.

Comment: TL;DR: Apply again. Long story: can we see the refusal letter?

Comment: Viv: please scan the refusal notice, crossing out your identifying information, and upload to your question (use the *edit* to add it). This would enable users to respond, or to point you to other questions here that address the issue(s) 
 (closing your question as a duplicate).

Comment: please how do i attach the document as i cannot see attach button?

Comment: @viv, use the *edit* button as Giorgio advised you above, and add the scan to your original question..

Comment: @Giorgio . i have added the picture.

Comment: One more clarification: did your supporting documents (e.g., bank statements, client contracts) show that your income is as you stated it (£50k annually)?

Comment: @Giorgio, yes i did and ECO saw them too. take a look at the attached document, ECO quoted my yearly income correctly in my country's currency but made a mistake while converting. He typed 24,000,000.00 NGN in my refusal letter but was considering it to be 2,400,00.00 NGN base on the mistake he made by typing £5,009.78 instead of £50,097.78. The mistake is on that refusal letter.

Comment: WHy is this tagged "uk-citizens" and "uk-residents"? If you're an UK citizen, then you shouldn't have need of a visa in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

The maths are incorrect and, as other users are suggesting, should your application be watertight in all other regards, you could pursue two options.

Option 1
Fax/email the visa application centre that handled your application. You will not be able to connect directly with the visa section that made the decision, as they are protected (and prohibited) from contact with the public (against corruption). For Nigeria, that would be [TLSContact](https://uk.tlscontact.com/ng/abv/splash.php). You would have to select the correct location ([Abuja](https://uk.tlscontact.com/ng/abv/inquiry.php), [Lagos-Victoria Island](https://uk.tlscontact.com/ng/lgv/inquiry.php), [Lagos-Ikeja](https://uk.tlscontact.com/ng/los/inquiry.php)) for the electronic contact form. Make your representation, succinctly: the maths noted in the refusal are not accurate, full stop. Avoid accusations, defensiveness, hot words.

Option 2
Contact the [UKVI help desk](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english), a fee-based service:

> By phone
>   Telephone: 00 44 203 481 1736
>   Monday to Friday, 24 hours
>   Calls cost £1.37 per minute on top of your standard network charges.
>
> By email
>   [Email UK Visas and Immigration.](https://contact-ukvi.homeoffice.gov.uk/app/international/payment/language/English) 
>   Emails enquiries cost £5.48. You will not be charged for any follow-up emails about the same enquiry.
>
> You’ll get a reply to your email within 2 days, except on Saturdays, Sundays and [UK public holidays](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays).

Comment: The OP can also email the embassy in his home country and where the UKVI regional hub is based.

Answer (score 2):

You can email the [Independent Chief Inspector of Borders and Immigration](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/independent-chief-inspector-of-borders-and-immigration). You can also email the [consular section of British High Commission Accra](https://www.gov.uk/world/organisations/british-high-commission-accra). See the contacts at the bottom of each page.

However before doing so - or before submitting another application, which is also an option - you need to make sure that your **submitted** application is airtight. Besides what Giorgio suggested in comments (bank statements and client contracts) I would also suggest adding more evidence stating what exactly you do, and why your pay is so good. I am unfamiliar with job market in Ghana, but [according to this post](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-average-salaries-in-Accra-Ghana-and-would-an-expat-live-comfortably-with-a-USD1500-monthly-gross-salary) a much smaller salary is already considered very high for Accra. ECOs are familiar with local salaries, and since your income is significantly higher, it is better to provide further  evidence confirming your credentials and salary. Don't treat it lightly - 50K GBP a year is quite impressive income even for UK. You might provide your resume, reference letters from clients, and so on.

Also here I assume you've been working on this job for quite some time. If you started it, you should probably wait 6+ months at least to prove this is not just one time windfall.

Finally, the evidence of your lifestyle matching your income could also serve an additional evidence. Owning a property in an affluent neighborhood and a decent car shows that you indeed receive this kind of income, and can afford your visit.

Comment: Thanks. My country is Nigeria not Ghana and my form was correctly filled and contains all the evidence in my statement of account. I want you to look at the attached document clearly and you will spot the mistake the ECO made. ECO stated my yearly income in my country currency accurately which is 24,000,000.00 NGN but on converting the currency base on £1=479.063, he made the mistake of equating it to £5,009.78 instead of £50,097.78 thereby omitting the 7 after 9. He typed 24,000,00.00 NGN correctly but was seeing the same figure as 2,400,00.00 NGN which he used in judging the visa.

Comment: @viv George sees the mistake - I think we all do - so there's no need to keep pointing it out.  His point, and I think it's a good one, is there's no win involved in drawing their attention to this error, and having them review the application, if the application immediately fails on *other* grounds related to your salary.  Be sure that you have **watertight** evidence that you do indeed enjoy an annual salary of 24MNGN, and have done so for a good six-month period.  If you did not submit such evidence with the first application, then a second (with it) may be a better idea.