# UK visa refusal error by the ECO

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

My visa application was refused because ECO believed I didn't address how I bought my property in which I did demonstrate but failed to acknowledge it.

Does anyone have an email to contact the embassy for a review?

Comment: Please add a scan of the refusal letter (after having blocked out all personal information) to your question, so we can see its wording and content.

Comment: [Related](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117979/ukvi-eco-made-a-mistake-on-my-visa-decision). As stated in the answer to that question, you ought to contact your application centre in the first instance. Note that UK consulates no longer have any involvement in visa applications, so it's unlikely to be worth contacting them.

Comment: @Romot Machine Are you sure you proved how you bought your property right back to the source of the funds? For example, showing £xx in your account which you used to buy the property isn’t enough. You need to prove where £xx came from, right back to its origin. If you inherited it, or were given it, or obtained it from a previous property sale etc they might even want you to prove that. As well as objecting to ‘funds parking’ strategies, the UK is very keen on making sure all funds purportedly belonging to an applicant were legally obtained eg no hint of potential money laundering, tax evasion